# Visual test of Activity

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, android-activity

Is there method to test(with mock data) one activity only? My app has about 30 activities and if I need to launch particular one I have to skip several activities.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to test an Activity, some examples are:

[Android Testing Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html)

[Activity Testing Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/activity_test.html)

Use [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/)

Use [Robotium](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/)